# Find H such as |Aut(ZxG)| = |Aut(ZxH)|, where G is a given finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, gap, computational-algebra

I am really new in GAP, please accept my apologize if my question is a simple one.
 I want to implement an algorithm in GAP for the next problem:

```
Given an abelian finite group G, find the group H such as
```

$$|Aut(Z \times G)| = |Aut(Z\times H)|$$
Honestly, I do not have a clear idea of how to implement it. I began with the calculation of direct product $\mathbb(Z \times G)$, using $DirectProduct(FreeGroup(1), G)$, then I called the following method,  $AutomorphismGroup(Z\times G)$, in order to get the automorphism group of $Z \times G$. I am not sure if this is a good approach, but it is the only idea that came up at the moment.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $Z$ supposed to denote the integers? And what do you mean by "*the* group $H$ such as..."? Are you implying there is only one such group? Because certainly $G=H$ will do the trick.

Comment: Yes, Z denotes the integers and no for the second part of the answer. I wanted to say "one of the group H such as..."

Comment: Do you have nontrivial examples?  What properties do $G$ and $H$ share? Is $|H|$ bounded in terms of $|G|$? Can you show that the result would hold by replacing $Z$ with $Z/m$ for a sufficiently large $m$? There is a lot of theoretical detail that needs sorting out before one can try to have the computer solve it. (e.g. `AutomorphismGroup` so far only works for finite groups.)

Comment: This thing is not proved in mathematics so that's the idea of this implementation: to find out if there are such abelian finite groups H and then to display its elements or their properties. And no, I do not have a nontrivial example.

Comment: @RobertCorman  Ok. Do you also want $H$ to be abelian? The first step towards finding an algorithm would be to make the problem finite. Can you factor out a subgroup of $Z$, so that the equality still holds if you replace $Z$ with this quotient?